# Renovar la IP de Tor en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import requests
import time
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://localhost:9050','https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'}
    return session

def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password = 'pass')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        controller.close()

nombres=['User1','User2','User3','User4']

for nombre in nombres:
    print nombre
    renew_connection()
    session = get_tor_session()
    print(session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text)
    time.sleep(5)
    print ' '
```

Con este código lo que pretendo es tener una IP diferente con cada nombre de la lista *nombres*.

El caso es que en vez de conseguir una ip distinta para cada nombre, lo que consigo es que '*User1*' y '*User2*' tengan una IP, y '*User3*' y '*User4*', otra IP distinta. Cuando tendría que ser una IP distinta para cada nombre.

**¿Como podría conseguir una IP distinta para cada nombre?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la renovación de la ip tarda un tiempo indeterminado en tener lugar. Este cambio se realiza de forma asíncrona y mientras tanto es usada la id anterior. El problema es que 5 segundos no son suficientes para este cambio, usándose la id anterior para la conexión.

Lo que puedes hacer es aumentar el tiempo de espera, o algo más robusto como:

```
import requests
import time
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://localhost:9050','https': 'socks5://localhost:9050'}
    return session

def renew_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
        controller.authenticate(password = 'torpass1010')
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        controller.close()

nombres=['User1','User2','User3','User4']



for nombre in nombres:
    session = get_tor_session()
    new_ip = old_ip = session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text
    renew_connection()
    while old_ip == new_ip:
        session = get_tor_session()
        new_ip = session.get("http://httpbin.org/ip").text
        time.sleep(5)
    old_ip = new_ip

    print(nombre)
    print(new_ip)
```